# Set Post Image Using Shortcode

Tags: images, shortcode, post-thumbnails

How can I set a post's featured image using the content of a shortcode? For instance, the following shortcode should set the post's featured image to the image at `www.google.de/nicepic.jpg`:

```
[post_image]www.google.de/nicepic.jpg[/post_image]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Shortcode API is more geared for altering post content rather than performing actions in response to content, and as such tend to require more creativity to alter other post data - though it can still be done. Ultimately, using a shortcode to set a featured image is kind of bizarre considering that you can do the same thing by clicking a button in the post editor UI.

*I emphasize that my solutions below are untested hacks that rely on using WordPress components in non-standard ways*

---

### Solution

Use [the Plugin API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API) to [write a plugin](https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin) that uses [the Shortcode API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) to [register your shortcode](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_shortcode).

In order to set a remote image as the featured image, you'll need to download the image, move it to a permanent location (such as `wp-content/uploads`), attach it to the post, then set the featured image. There are a few ways to accomplish this, but I think the most straightforward would be to

1. Use [`download_url()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/download_url) to download the remote image to the temporary directory.
2. Pass the temporary filepath to [`handle_media_sideload()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/media_handle_sideload) to move the file to `wp-content/uploads`, generate attachment metadata, and attach it to the post.
3. Pass the returned attachment ID to [`set_post_thumbnail()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/set_post_thumbnail) to specify it as the featured image.

The tricky part about applying the above in  a shortcode's callback function is that `handle_media_sideload()` and `set_post_thumbnail()` both require the post's ID, and shortcode callbacks are not passed the post ID nor the post object itself. The have access to this data when shortcodes are applied to posts getting displayed in The Loop by way of the global `$post` object, however applying the above operation at that point could result in the image being downloaded and set every time the post was displayed.

One possible work-around to achieve the hack would be to use a class property to pass the post ID, and return early from the shortcode callback the shortcode's contents weren't modified.

---

### Alternate Solution

A simpler hack may be to manually extract the remote image URL from the post's contents on an action hook that fires when a post is saved (such as `save_post`). A shortcode could still be registered to return a blank string. Something along the lines of

```
$featured_image_shortcode = 'post_image';

wpse_211802_featured_image_shortcode( $atts, $content ) {
  return '';
}

add_shortcode( $featured_image_shortcode, 'wpse_211802_featured_image_shortcode' );

wpse_211802_featured_image_from_shortcode_url( $post_id ) {
  $content           = get_the_content( $post_id );
  $shortcode_matches = array();
  
  if( ! has_shortcode( $content, 'post_image' ) )
    return;
  
  preg_match_all( '\[' . $featured_image_shortcode . '\](.*)\[\/' . $featured_image_shortcode . '\]', $content, $shortcode_matches );
  
  $url      = $shortcode_matches[ 1 ][ 0 ];
  $tempfile = download_url( $url );
  
  if( is_wp_error( $tempfile ) ){
    // download failed, handle error
    return;
  }

  // Set variables for storage
  preg_match( '/[^\?]+\.(jpg|jpe|jpeg|gif|png)/i', $url, $matches );

  $desc       = 'Featured Image for Post ' . $post_id;
  $file_array = array(
    'name'     => basename( $matches[0] ),
    'tmp_name' => $tempfile
  );

  // Sideload the downloaded file as an attachment to this post
  $attachment_id = media_handle_sideload( $file_array, $post_id, $desc );

  // If errors encountered while sideloading, delete the downloaded file
  if ( is_wp_error( $attachment_id ) ) {
    @unlink( $tempfile );
    return;
  }
  
  // If all went well, set the featured image
  set_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $attachment_id );
}

add_action( 'save_post', 'wpse_211802_featured_image_from_shortcode_url' );
```

You may need to `require_once()` additional files in order for the above to function. If you do something similar, I'd recommend expanding upon the error handling and URL validation.

Still though - far easier to just set the featured image with the button on the post editor UI.

Comment: I tried this - but it is not working. I don't know why - but not a single image upload from url sample is working. My own function based on the wordpress.com sample is also not working...

Comment: Hey, it's just an idea - didn't say it would work exactly as I wrote it ;) . But the general approach should yield a solution. You can always try to [troubleshoot it](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress). Or implement it the way I suggested as the first solution. I'm not sure what "the wordpress.com sample" is, but the WordPress Development community doesn't tend to have much to do with wordpress.com - it's mostly a Q&A site for the self-hosted WordPress installations of the WordPress project at wordpress.org.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Now I have a working prototype.

Answer (score 0):

Not a full answer, but maybe a hint in the right direction...

In terms of saved data, a featured image is actually a custom field named `_thumbnail_id` that holds the numeric ID of the image attachment.

When exporting your posts as XML, it shows up like this:

```
<wp:postmeta>
  <wp:meta_key>_thumbnail_id</wp:meta_key>
  <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[1497]]></wp:meta_value>
</wp:postmeta>`
```

So you could try to add images programmatically by using [add_post_meta()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_post_meta).

Using external image URLs won't be that easy though, as WordPress doesn't allow them for Featured Images.

Comment: Ohh ... I see. In this case I think I should add the image to my wordpress media library?! But I think this is not that easy....

Comment: Indeed probably not that easy... I would opt for an easier workaround, such as (1) just adding the image URL to your own custom field, and (2) tweaking your theme so that it gets displayed the same way as the featured image would.